# Difference in the process of static and dynamic compilation of modules in APache

Tags: apache-2.4

I am confused about the difference in the static and dynamic compilation of external modules in apache. Could somebody explain that with respect to mod_qos?

Also what is the difference with the following way of loading modules in httpd.conf file?

```
    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule reqtimeout_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    </IfModule>
```

As you can see, the former one references .c file in the directive whereas the latter doesn't? WHy is that and how does it change the inclusion of the module?

Thanks. I am a novice in apache so please don't mind if the question sounds silly.

Comment: You've lost some of the markup as there's just two `DirectoryIndex` lines which look identica to me. I suspect you've tried to include some `<tag>`'s which have been removed, these need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Static modules are compiled into the `httpd` binary when the server is built, while dynamic modules are included at runtime. In [Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/dso.html), almost all distributed modules are added in dynamically. This is important, because if a module is updated you would have to recompile the `httpd` binary to apply the update if you statically compiled.

The naming conventions are just [*alternative* ways to refer to a module in the `<IfModule>` Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#ifmodule), and has nothing to do with how the module is compiled.

As noted in the documentation, the module can be referred to by `module-file` *or* `module-identifier`.

> For example, `rewrite_module` is the identifier and `mod_rewrite.c` is the file name.

NOTE (in an attempt to extend answer for your duplicate question): To dynamically load the module `foo_module` in *your* server, put the `mod_foo.so` file in the same directory as all of the other modules, and add a `LoadModule` directive in the same format as all of the other one's in your main Apache `.conf` file (which will refer properly to the right path).